# Object Property Value in javascript

Tags: javascript

How property value being assigned in below code:

```
var foo = {};
var bar = {};
var obj = {};

obj[foo] = "Nishan";
obj[bar] = "Manis";


console.log(obj[foo]);
```

Why it giving output "Manis"

```
var foo = {};
var bar = {};
var obj = {};

obj.foo = "Nishan";
obj.bar = "Manis";

console.log(obj.foo);

Output: "Nishan"
```

What is difference between declare property of object by using "." and "[]"
Ex: obj.far = "Nish" and obj[far] = "Nish"

```
var foo = {};
var bar = {};
var obj = {};

obj.foo = "Nishan";
obj.bar = "Manis";

console.log(obj[foo]);
```

Giving undefined

Answer (score 6):

An object is valid as a key only because it's converted to a string, and the string representation of an object is `[object Object]`, so what you're doing is equal to

```
var obj = {};

obj[`[object Object]`] = "Nishan";
obj[`[object Object]`] = "Manis";

console.log( obj[`[object Object]`] ); // returns Manis
```

So basically you're overwriting the key / value pair as the string representation of `foo` and `bar` is the same thing, they are both converted to `[object Object]`

**EDIT :**

In the second and third example you do something like

```
var foo = {};

obj.foo = "something";
```

but when you're using dot notation you can declare any property you want, and the property `foo` on the object has nothing to do with the variable `foo` declared above, they are not even remotely related, you might as well do

```
var foo = {};

obj.didgeridoo = "something";
```

the relevance is the same, nothing.

Answer (score 3):

When you access a property using square bracket notation, you have to pass a string in.

`foo` and `bar` are both objects.

When you convert an object to a string, by default, you get a result like `"[Object object]"`.

`foo.toString() === bar.toString()` so `obj[foo] === obj[bar]`.